# How to force / interrupt / update route navigation in Google Maps app?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Say my app launches the Google Maps app to provide turn-by-turn navigation. At some point my app needs to amend / update the route for the user so I relaunch the Google Maps app with an updated set of parameters.

Google Maps gives a silent, short time-out pop-up to the user with:

**You're navigating a route**

**Stop navigating this route?**

**Cancel / YES, STOP**

and defaults to Cancel.

This is fairly confusing to me/the user, since I would want the user to tap "YES, STOP" but who would select stop?.. and there's no stopping... the route would just be recalculated when selecting "stop".

Is there an uri parameter to force the Google Maps app to "YES, STOP" and continue with the new route?

I understand the "intent" of the pop-up "feature" but at the same time there should be an easy way to bypass it.. ie. app that launches.. can update.. or route with key id X can be updated by new route with key id X etc...

So does anyone know or it's just another case of once I start down the Google Maps rabbit hole, I can't stop 'till I hit the bottom?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Do u find any solution in ios ?

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is relaunch the intent to navigate and destroy the previous intent's stack:

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
mapIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This will cause the previous state of the navigation to be destroyed in favor of the new one. You won't even be asked to interrupt the previous navigation.