# Not able to open Google Maps Turn By Turn Navigation: Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, android-intent, navigation

I am trying to integrate the following functionality into my flutter app-
**When a user clicks a Navigate button, it should redirect the user to Google Maps App and start Turn by Turn Navigation (which we generally use) **
I am using the following code- (just an example error message although I am using latitude and longitude which gives similar error)

```
               ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                String mapsUrl =
                                    'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=${appState.position.latitude},${appState.position.longitude}&destination=${riderLocation.latitude},${appState.position.longitude}&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate';
                                 Uri uri = Uri.parse(mapsUrl);  
                               
                              
                                if (await canLaunchUrl(mapsUrl)) {
                                  print('can launch url true');
                                  await launchUrl(
                                    Uri.parse(mapsUrl),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  print('Could not launch url');
                                  throw 'Could not launch $mapsUrl';
                                }
                              },
```

**Problem:**
When I press the navigate button, google maps gets opened in WebView, showing the complete path and an option **Navigate in App**. When I click it, I get an error message like-

Web page not available
The web page at intent://maps.app.goo.gl/?link=https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Barcelona,%2BSpain/Zaragoza,%2BSpain/Huesca,%2BSpain/Madrid,%2BSpain/@41.2603069,-0.7768843,5z/data%3D!4m14!4m13!1m2!1m1!1s0x12a49816718e30e5:0x44b0fb3d4f47660a!1m2!1m1!1s0xd5914dd5e618e91:0x49df13f1158489a8!1m2!1m1!1s0xd584449d1d84db5:0x2c8dfd864aa74791!1m2!1m1!1s0xd422997800a3c81:0xc436dec1618c2269!3e0?entry%3Dml&apn=com.google.android.apps.maps&amv=965100030&isi=585027354&ibi=com.google.Maps&ius=comgooglemapsurl&utm_campaign=ml_promo&ct=ml-dr-wv-msc&mt=8&pt=9008&efr=1#Intent;package=com.google.android.gms;scheme=https;S.browser_fallback_url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.google.android.apps.maps&pcampaignid%3Dfdl_long&url%3Dhttps://www.google.com/maps/dir/Barcelona,%252BSpain/Zaragoza,%252BSpain/Huesca,%252BSpain/Madrid,%252BSpain/@41.2603069,-0.7768843,5z/data%253D!4m14!4m13!1m2!1m1!1s0x12a49816718e30e5:0x44b0fb3d4f47660a!1m2!1m1!1s0xd5914dd5e618e91:0x49df13f1158489a8!1m2!1m1!1s0xd584449d1d84db5:0x2c8dfd864aa74791!1m2!1m1!1s0xd422997800a3c81:0xc436dec1618c2269!3e0%3Fentry%253Dml&min_version%3D965100030;end; could not be loaded because:

**net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**

An image of what I want on button press-
https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2Fuy1dU.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F35967239%2Fandroid-google-map-turn-by-turn-navigation&tbnid=DZTxUO10KEw4_M&vet=12ahUKEwiE4Oji-rf5AhU9i9gFHVOXCeIQMygAegUIARCwAQ..i&docid=vB080_l2mo_iNM&w=480&h=854&q=google%20maps%20turn%20by%20turn%20navigation&ved=2ahUKEwiE4Oji-rf5AhU9i9gFHVOXCeIQMygAegUIARCwAQ

Comment: I suggest using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher). The documentation contains instructions how to set url schemes.

Comment: I did not find any method to directly open turn by turn navigation. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I use it to let the user select one of the navigation apps installed on the phone. After this the package opens the app with the navigation target set, but the user has to click 'Start' or something similar in order to start the navigation. I think it is not possible to start the navigation without user interaction.

Comment: Can you help me figure out why the above error is raised when I try to open the app from webview?

Comment: I think you need to set `intent-filter` for the url schema in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: try with waypoints like this.


https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=43.7967876,-79.5331616&destination=43.5184049,-79.8473993&waypoints=43.1941283,-79.59179|43.7991083,-79.5339667|43.8387033,-79.3453417|43.836424,-79.3024487&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last year Google had a major incident with this feature on both iOs and Android, and they changed something about how it behaves.

For Android the only working way to open the actual app instead of the web representation is to make a proper Android Intent that targets the Google Maps application, while for iOs the old URL launching should work as it was before.
The difference is in the URI of what should be launched.

For Android:

```
Uri get uri => Uri(
        scheme: 'google.navigation',
        host: '',
        queryParameters: {
          'q': '${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}',
          'mode': 'd',
        },
      );

    AndroidIntent intent;
    const action = AndroidIntentAction.view;
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39037306/1627511
    final flags = [
      Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK,
      Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
    ];
    intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: action,
      flags: flags,
      data: uri.toString(),
      package: 'com.google.android.apps.maps',
    );
    if (await intent.canResolveActivity() == true) {
        await intent.launch();
      }
```

For iOs

```
Uri get uri => Uri(
        scheme: 'comgooglemaps',
        host: '',
        queryParameters: {
          'daddr': '${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}',
          'directionsmode': 'driving',
        },
      );
await launchUrlString(uri.toString()); // launch this via https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
```

**Bonus** For browser

```
Uri get uri => Uri(
        scheme: 'https',
        host: 'www.google.com',
        path: 'maps/dir/',
        queryParameters: {
          'api': '1',
          'destination': '${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}',
          'travelmode': 'driving',
          'dir_action': 'navigate',
        },
      );
await launchUrlString(uri.toString()); // launch this via https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
```

Hope it helps